# Renumber MATLAB figure without saving and opening .fig file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In MATLAB R2011b, I have a script which explicitly specifies a figure number (say, Figure 1) and plots on it. I wish to keep this plot open and run the script again with different parameters, so that I can visually compare the new and previous plots.

How can I rename the previous figure (to, say, Figure 2) so that the new plot does not overwrite it, and thus allowing both plots to be visible, without

- Modifying the script, or
- Saving the previous figure as a .fig file and reopening it as another figure

from both

1. The command line, and
2. using the figure's GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getobj` to copy the contents of one figure to another:

```
% get handle of the old figure
oldFigHandle = gcf;

% create new figure 
newFigHandle = figure+1;

% copy the contents from one figure the other
copyobj(get(oldFigHandle , 'children'), newFigHandle);
```

Other properties can be copied using the `set` and `get` commands:

```
set(newFigHandle, 'color', get(oldFigHandle , 'color'));
```

Comment: Many thanks, H.Muster. It works, except not all properties are copied over e.g. the figure background colour. I could set it manually, but is there a way to automatically copy everything over?

Comment: I am not aware of a method to copy all properties at once, but you can copy each separately, e.g. for the background: `copyobj(get(oldFigHandle , 'background'), newFigureHandle);`. See `get(oldFigHandle)` for all properties.

Comment: As I get "The name 'Background' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'figure'.", I presume you meant 'Color'. With 'Color' I get "Object figure[1] can not be a child of parent figure[1]" even though using 'Children' works.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken, `copyobj` only works for handles. Use `set(newFigureHandle), 'color', get(oldFigHandle , 'color')` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Fix for a minor typo: `set(newFigureHandle, 'color', get(oldFigHandle, 'color'))` i.e. the first ")" should be moved to the end.

Comment: One thing I noticed not copied over is which toolbar is visible, and which tool is selected (e.g. pan or 3D rotate). Is it possible to copy these to the new figure too?

Comment: Frankly, I do not know. I tried but did not manage to copy the selected tool.

Answer (score 2):

Based on H.Muster's answer, I wrote this function to clone a figure:

```
%% Clone a figure
%  clone_figure()     - Clone the current figure to a new figure
%  clone_figure(N)    - Clone the current figure to figure N
%  clone_figure(0, M) - Clone figure M to a new figure
%  clone_figure(N, M) - Clone figure M to a figure N
function clone_figure(new_index, old_index)
    % Get handle of original figure
    if (exist('old_index', 'var'))
        if (not(ishandle(old_index)))
            error('myApp:argChk', ['Figure ',num2str(old_index),' undefined']);
        end
        figure(old_index);
    end
    old_handle = gcf;
    % Get handle of clone
    if (exist('new_index', 'var') && new_index)
        if (new_index < 0)
            error('myApp:argChk', ['Index ',num2str(new_index),' invalid']);
        end
        figure(new_index);
    else
        figure;
    end
    new_handle = gcf;
    % Copy figure's contents and properties
    copyobj(get(old_handle, 'Children'), new_handle);
    copyobj(get(old_handle, 'CurrentAxes'), new_handle);
    set(new_handle, 'Alphamap', get(old_handle, 'Alphamap'));
    set(new_handle, 'CloseRequestFcn', get(old_handle, 'CloseRequestFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'Color', get(old_handle, 'Color'));
    set(new_handle, 'Colormap', get(old_handle, 'Colormap'));
    set(new_handle, 'CurrentPoint', get(old_handle, 'CurrentPoint'));
    set(new_handle, 'DockControls', get(old_handle, 'DockControls'));
    set(new_handle, 'FileName', get(old_handle, 'FileName'));
    set(new_handle, 'IntegerHandle', get(old_handle, 'IntegerHandle'));
    set(new_handle, 'InvertHardcopy', get(old_handle, 'InvertHardcopy'));
    set(new_handle, 'KeyPressFcn', get(old_handle, 'KeyPressFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'KeyReleaseFcn', get(old_handle, 'KeyReleaseFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'MenuBar', get(old_handle, 'MenuBar'));
    set(new_handle, 'Name', get(old_handle, 'Name'));
    set(new_handle, 'NextPlot', get(old_handle, 'NextPlot'));
    set(new_handle, 'NumberTitle', get(old_handle, 'NumberTitle'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperUnits', get(old_handle, 'PaperUnits'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperOrientation', get(old_handle, 'PaperOrientation'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperPosition', get(old_handle, 'PaperPosition'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperPositionMode', get(old_handle, 'PaperPositionMode'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperSize', get(old_handle, 'PaperSize'));
    set(new_handle, 'PaperType', get(old_handle, 'PaperType'));
    set(new_handle, 'Pointer', get(old_handle, 'Pointer'));
    set(new_handle, 'PointerShapeCData', get(old_handle, 'PointerShapeCData'));
    set(new_handle, 'PointerShapeHotSpot', get(old_handle, 'PointerShapeHotSpot'));
    set(new_handle, 'Position', get(old_handle, 'Position'));
    set(new_handle, 'Renderer', get(old_handle, 'Renderer'));
    set(new_handle, 'RendererMode', get(old_handle, 'RendererMode'));
    set(new_handle, 'Resize', get(old_handle, 'Resize'));
    set(new_handle, 'ResizeFcn', get(old_handle, 'ResizeFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'SelectionType', get(old_handle, 'SelectionType'));
    set(new_handle, 'ToolBar', get(old_handle, 'ToolBar'));
    set(new_handle, 'Units', get(old_handle, 'Units'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowButtonDownFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowButtonUpFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowKeyPressFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowKeyPressFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowKeyReleaseFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowKeyReleaseFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowScrollWheelFcn', get(old_handle, 'WindowScrollWheelFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'WindowStyle', get(old_handle, 'WindowStyle'));
    set(new_handle, 'WVisual', get(old_handle, 'WVisual'));
    set(new_handle, 'WVisualMode', get(old_handle, 'WVisualMode'));
    set(new_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn', get(old_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'Clipping', get(old_handle, 'Clipping'));
    set(new_handle, 'CreateFcn', get(old_handle, 'CreateFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'DeleteFcn', get(old_handle, 'DeleteFcn'));
    set(new_handle, 'BusyAction', get(old_handle, 'BusyAction'));
    set(new_handle, 'HandleVisibility', get(old_handle, 'HandleVisibility'));
    set(new_handle, 'HitTest', get(old_handle, 'HitTest'));
    set(new_handle, 'Interruptible', get(old_handle, 'Interruptible'));
    set(new_handle, 'Parent', get(old_handle, 'Parent'));
    set(new_handle, 'Selected', get(old_handle, 'Selected'));
    set(new_handle, 'SelectionHighlight', get(old_handle, 'SelectionHighlight'));
    set(new_handle, 'Tag', get(old_handle, 'Tag'));
    set(new_handle, 'UIContextMenu', get(old_handle, 'UIContextMenu'));
    set(new_handle, 'UserData', get(old_handle, 'UserData'));
    set(new_handle, 'Visible', get(old_handle, 'Visible'));
    % from get(gcf) but skip CurrentCharacter, CurrentObject, BeingDeleted, Type
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just spoke with a Mathworks employee and was told that a better solution is to set the 'HandleVisibility' parameter of the figure to 'off' to protect it. For example, to keep figures 1 and 2, do

```
 set(1:2, 'HandleVisibility', 'off')
```

MATLAB will then map any reference to these figures to new figures, so that the originals (including tool settings) remain untouched.

Though this doesn't exactly answer the question, it achieves what I wanted to do.

Comment: To also copy whether a figure is docked e.g. figure 1's to figure 3's, do set(3, 'WindowStyle', get(1, 'Windowstyle')). (Alternatively, do set(0, 'DefaultFigureWindowStyle', 'Docked') to dock all new figures.)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/figure.html

You can just save a handle to the [current figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gcf.html)

```
h = [];
for i = 1:NumGraphs
    h(i) = gcf;
    figure;

    %Your code to create the next graph here
end
```

Then to get back a specific graph:

```
figure(h(i));
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. When I did "h(i) = gcf;" , I got "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." Presumably i was treated as sqrt(-1). Trying "h = gcf;" instead, all it does is to return to the original figure with the same number (Figure 1); if I now plot on figure 1, I lose the original plot. What I wish to do is to rename figure 1 to, say, figure 2, so that when I plot to figure 1, the original figure is preserved.

Comment: Yeah first declare i as a variable, so i = 1. I assumed you wanted to do this in a loop or something, just replace i with the number you want. But be sure to store each figure in a different index of h.